# How show back button in screen component in react navigaton

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

I use my own header in React Navigation and according to the documentation there is such a [description](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator#header):

```
Custom header to use instead of the default header.

This accepts a function that returns a React Element to display as a header. The function receives an object containing the following properties as the argument:

navigation - The navigation object for the current screen.
route - The route object for the current screen.
options - The options for the current screen
back - Options for the back button, contains an object with a title property to use for back button label.
Example:

import { getHeaderTitle } from '@react-navigation/elements';

// ..

header: ({ navigation, route, options, back }) => {
  const title = getHeaderTitle(options, route.name);

  return (
    <MyHeader
      title={title}
      leftButton={
        back ? <MyBackButton onPress={navigation.goBack} /> : undefined
      }
      style={options.headerStyle}
    />
  );
};

To set a custom header for all the screens in the navigator, you can specify this option in the screenOptions prop of the navigator.

Note that if you specify a custom header, the native functionality such as large title, search bar etc. won't work.
```

The `header` property accepts the `back` parameter which can be undefined or an object with the `title` property and used this code and now wants to determine whether to show me a **Back Button** or not, just like in the code example, but I don't I know how to cause the appearance of this button from the screen or through a property in the `Stack.Screen` component, the only thing I came up with is to rewrite the header like this:

```js
const SomeScreen = () => {
  const { navigation } = useNavigator()

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation
      .setOptions({ header: () =>  (
        <MyHeader
          title={title}
          leftButton={<MyBackButton onPress={navigation.goBack} />}
          style={options.headerStyle}
        />
      )});
  }, [])

  return (
    <Layout>
      <View style={[screenStyles.screenTopPadding, screenStyles.screenPadding]}>
      </View>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

How can I tell the `back` parameter to perform a ternary operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to provoke the change of back from undefine to an object, but I found a more correct solution in my opinion. It consists in using the `headerBackVisible` property with options that are passed to the same header method:

```js
header: ({ navigation, route, options: { headerBackVisible }, back }) => {
  ...

  return (
    <MyHeader
      title={title}
      leftButton={
        headerBackVisible ? <MyBackButton onPress={navigation.goBack} /> : undefined
      }
      style={options.headerStyle}
    />
  );
};
```

After that, I wrote a hook that should be used in the Screen on which this change should be turned on/off:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { Routes } from '@/config/routes'
import { ScreenNavigation } from '@/navigation/types'
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native'

const useBackArrow = (isShow: boolean, parents: Routes[]): void => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const isFocused = useIsFocused()

  useEffect(() => {
    let parent = navigation
    while (parents.length !== 0) {
      const route = parents.shift() as Routes

      parent = parent.getParent<ScreenNavigation<typeof route>>()
    }

    if (!isFocused) {
      return
    }

    parent.setOptions({ headerBackVisible: isShow })
  }, [isShow, parents, navigation, isFocused])
}

export default useBackArrow
```

And I use it as follows:

```js
const SomeScreen = () => {
  useBackArrow(true, [/** parents navigator if is no root */])

  return (
    <Layout>
      <View>
        Some screen
      </View>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default SomeScreen
```

The disadvantages of such an approach are that you need to add this hook in a circle so that the state of the arrow corresponds to what you want, maybe there is a better solution to this problem in the community, if so I will wait for your answer.